# Как скрыть сайдбар на сайте wordpress от поисковых роботов (в коде страницы CTRL+U )?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, seo, поисковая-оптимизация

Уже несколько дней и ночей бьюсь над задачей.

Никак не могу понять, каким образом на сайтах скрывают от поисковых роботов кусок контента.

Взять к примеру сайт https://www.vedomosti.ru/

У них сайдбар рендерится и виден в DOM-Дереве.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при просмотре кода страницы, сайдбар практически отсутствует. И через поиск ни одного названия статьи не удаётся найти.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Всё, что я смог найти в коде страницы касаемо сайдбара:

```
<aside class="the-sidebar">
   <div class="the-sidebar__toggle-wrapper">
   <div class="the-sidebar__toggle">
     <svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="svg-icon svg-fill" style="width:20px;height:20px;"><path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" pid="0" d="M15.5 10.75H8v-1.5h7.5v1.5zM8 7.25h7.5v-1.5H8v1.5zm7.5 7H8v-1.5h7.5v1.5zM5.5 7.5a1 1 0 100-2 1 1 0 000 2zm1 2.5a1 1 0 11-2 0 1 1 0 012 0zm-1 4.5a1 1 0 100-2 1 1 0 000 2z" _fill="#000"></path><path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" pid="1" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M1 1v18h18V1H1zm16.5 1.5h-15v15h15v-15z" _fill="#000"></path></svg> 
    <!---->
    </div>
</div> <div class="the-sidebar__close"><svg version="1.1" viewBox="0 0 18 18" class="svg-icon svg-fill" style="width:18px;height:24px;"><path fill="currentColor" stroke="none" pid="0" fill-rule="evenodd" d="M9 7.586L16.071.515l1.414 1.414L10.415 9l7.07 7.071-1.414 1.414L9 10.415l-7.071 7.07-1.414-1.414L7.585 9 .516 1.929 1.929.515z"></path></svg></div> 
<!---->
</aside>
```

А вот на сайте, над которым я работаю всё видно и в DOM-дереве и в коде страницы: https://m2.news/
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал выводить сайдбар посредством ajax запроса, но толку никакого - всё равно сайдбар видно в коде страницы.

Вот каким образом можно скрыть кусок разметки на сайте, в коде элемента, и от поисковых роботов, как на первом сайте? В какую сторону копать? Подскажите пожалуйста!

Второй сайт стоит на движке wordpress.

Comment: Все элементы, созданные с помощью js в браузере не будут видны в коде страницы.

Comment: Протестировал ещё раз на локальном сервере ajax запрос и действительно контент в коде страницы скрылся. Я наконец-то разобрался в этом вопросе. Спасибо вам!

Comment: Только вот наличие или отсутствие сайдбара в коде страницы не значит вообще ничего. Google bot умеет в Javascript.